# Only a something away from completing something

Tags: grammar, idioms, american-english, only

Is this statement grammatically correct:

> Only an Xbox One away from completing my Microsoft family.

I have a Microsoft Phone (Lumia 920), PC (Dell) and tablet (Surface Pro) and I just need a console now (Xbox One) so does that statement correctly tell a person that I just need an Xbox One now in order to complete my Microsoft [product] family (which includes phone, PC and tablet right now) ?

Comment: Sounds correct to me.

Comment: I think it would sound better if you use "One Xbox" than "Xbox One"

Answer (score 2):

It sounds a little awkward, because the object in question consists of two words, but this is a perfectly fine construction of a sentence.

As the comments pointed out, this word-swapping or phrase-swapping structure is one example of a [snowclone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowclone).

Comment: Yes. 'Only _ _____ away from completing _ ____ ' is an example of a snowclone. Only five dragoons away from completing my Balaclava diorama.

Comment: Ah, an absolutely wonderful expression.  Only one wikipedia page away from completing this Snowclone reference.